# it is possible have different editor styles in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, styles

Well in short i am a big fan of writing nice looking code, there is a great article here
[the beauty of doom 3 source code](http://kotaku.com/5975610/the-exceptional-beauty-of-doom-3s-source-code) I have been using different code editors before visual studio.
And i liked a compact writing style.
I dont like almost empty white lines like

```
public void my function(string s)
{                                          //almost empty line
   string n = domystuff();
   if (n=="blanc")
     {                                     //almost empty
        mycode("should start a row earlier on { line");
     }                                     //..
    else
     {
        ohno.notagain("another two blanc lines above and below else");
        Altough.it.compiles("equaly");
        myscreen.used = not.optimal;
     }
 }
```

If code is better written, then its nice to read, if something is nice to read with much white lines then the white lines spoil it. So i wonder can this auto-formatting be changed in VS2010 ?

Comment: If this is for in the workplace you should use the standard formatting scheme already used throughout your company for consistency and ease of use your co-workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# as a language has a set of coding conventions which C# programmers expect to be fairly consistent from project to project. If you want to use the One True Brace style, switch to Java.

If you insist on being the odd man out, you can configure the Visual Studio auto-formatter in Tools → Options... → Text Editor → C# → Formatting.

Comment: My company used his style through our code and it's to keep consistency across several projects. When you have almost 500k lines of code those lines really add up fast.

Comment: Thanks well i've always been the odd men, i just cannt make even.

Comment: that's remember me a recent reading. http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=A%20Brief%20History%20of%20CSharp%20Style&referringTitle=Documentation